# LuceneAppEngine dependency with Gradle

Tags: java, google-app-engine, android-studio, gradle, lucene

I have been trying to use the [Lucene-Appengine project](https://code.google.com/p/lucene-appengine/). Since I am using android studio, I go to [maven and I found](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.luceneappengine/luceneappengine/2.0.0) and added the dependency to my gradle file as

compile 'com.googlecode.luceneappengine:luceneappengine:2.0.0'

So yes I am very new to gradle (few days). But I was under the impression that gradle will pull all further dependencies that the project being pulled needs. But when I look in my file, I am still missing the lucene stuff such as

```
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.document.Document;
import org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexNotFoundException;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexReader;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriterConfig;
import org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.MultiFieldQueryParser;
import org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.ParseException;
import org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParser;
import org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher;
import org.apache.lucene.search.Query;
import org.apache.lucene.search.ScoreDoc;
import org.apache.lucene.search.TopScoreDocCollector;
```

What am I doing wrong? Am I implementing the Lucene-Appengine project wrong? Do I need to get the Lucene dependencies myself? I want to do this the right way. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well gradle will only pull down what it knows about.  If you look at the [maven repository site you linked to](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.luceneappengine/luceneappengine/2.0.0), it will show you what that dependency has dependencies on.

Or you can look at what grade thinks it should grab for your dependencies

```
./gradlew dependencies
```

On an empty project with just the luceneappengine dependency, the result is

```
compile - Compile classpath for source set 'main'.
\--- com.googlecode.luceneappengine:luceneappengine:2.0.0
     +--- javax.persistence:persistence-api:1.0.2
     +--- com.google.appengine:appengine-api-1.0-sdk:1.9.4
     +--- com.googlecode.objectify:objectify:5.0.2
     |    \--- com.google.guava:guava:14.0.1
     \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.7
```

From the look of things, **you probably have to explicitly add the lucene dependencies.**

I have no knowledge of lucene though, what is this dependency supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly add `lucene-core` dependency as specified in the [wiki page](https://github.com/UltimaPhoenix/luceneappengine/wiki/Usage-and-Configuration) (into an equivalent gradle import syntax). Probably you need to add other artifacts needed by your application, for example: `lucene-queries`, `lucene-queryparser`, `lucene-analyzers-common`, but they are not required by `luceneappengine` itself.
Be sure to add every artifact with the same Lucene version and to respect the [compatibility notes](https://github.com/UltimaPhoenix/luceneappengine/wiki/Versions).

You can find a full example [here](https://github.com/UltimaPhoenix/lucene-appengine-examples) (always maven).